# Add empty values to query result document fields that exist in the schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Example:

mongoose schema:

```
{
  fieldOne: String,
  fieldTwo: Array,
  fieldThree: Object
}
```

mongoDB:

```
{_id: 1, fieldOne: 'val1' },
{_id: 2, fieldOne: 'val2', fieldTwo: [val3, val4] },
{_id: 3, fieldOne: 'val5', fieldTwo: [val6, val7], fieldThree: {prop1: val8} },
{_id: 4, fieldTwo: [val9, val10], fieldThree: {prop1: val11} },
```

desired query result:

```
{_id: 1, fieldOne: 'val1', fieldTwo: [], fieldThree: {} },
{_id: 2, fieldOne: 'val2', fieldTwo: [val3, val4], fieldThree: {} },
{_id: 3, fieldOne: 'val5', fieldTwo: [val6, val7], fieldThree: {prop1: val8} },
{_id: 4, fieldOne: '', fieldTwo: [val9, val10], fieldThree: {prop1: val11} },
```

The solution I have in mind is to simply loop through the query result and then insert the empty values, but thought I'd ask here first to learn if there is another smarter/standard way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the purpose of sending empty properties?

Comment: Have you checked out [$ifNull](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)?

Comment: like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZigTExNKneR) ?

Comment: @JeremyFiel, while strings might not be a problem, I've had to work around undefined fields when dealing with objects and arrays. It's something I've postponed for a while, but I feel the workarounds are unnecessarily cluttering my code.

Comment: @cmgchess & ray, thanks a lot, that looks like a good solution. I've recently looked into the aggregation framework briefly, but the only tutorials I was able to find (including payed ones) were pretty basic. Do you know of any that does a deep dive, because I see that aggregation is quite versatile?

Comment: @ReneJorgensen havent really gone through tutorials other than docs, so answers. now that chatgpt is also there it is quite useful

Comment: Here's some wonderful reading
https://www.practical-mongodb-aggregations.com

Comment: $mergeObjects can be useful for adding default fields: https://mongoplayground.net/p/yD91M10u-F5